# MS SQL PDO won't retrieve data from table

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm attempting to get [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) up and running for my Apache server so I can use prepared statements when it interacts with my MS SQL database. It seems that the library is installed and that it connects okay, but I can't get it to return any information from a the table

```
   $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$database","$username","$password");
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
  }
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM asdf");
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
  print_r($result);  //prints nothing
  var_dump($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN|PDO::FETCH_GROUP)); //prints nothing
```

returns

```
**array(0) { }**
```

This however

```
  $dbh = new PDO("dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", "$username", "$password");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: ".$e - > getMessage()."\n";
}
$stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT @@VERSION");
$stmt - > execute();
while ($row = $stmt - > fetch()) {
    print_r($row);
}
unset($dbh);
unset($stmt);
```

Prints out the computers details.

**`Array ( [] => Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) [0] => Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1617.0 (X64) Apr 22 2011 19:23:43 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor) )`**

So I think PDO is working on some level. Have I just got some bad syntax?

Comment: Try checking the return value of `$stmt->execute();` to confirm the query was succesful.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Thanks. Do you mean like this: `print_r($stmt->execute());`? That didn't produce anything.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Actually I had a typo. `print_r($stmt->execute());` produces `Array ( )`

Comment: The return value of `$stmt->execute();` is true on success so I would do `$success = $stmt->execute(); if(!$success) { print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); die("DB Error");} ` http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse Give me: `Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 208 [2] => General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [(null)] [3] => -1 [4] => 16 ) DB Error`

Comment: Clearly your query is wrong / invalid or your SQL server is having issues. Try running the query on the server itself.

Comment: @PhilipWhitehouse you were right. It was an error in the query. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From troubleshooting in the comments...)*

Try checking the return value of `$stmt->execute();` to confirm the query was succesful.

The return value of `$stmt->execute();` is true on success so I would do:

```
$success = $stmt->execute(); 

if(!$success) {
   print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); 
   die("DB Error");
}
```